# Jasper report and InternalResourceViewResolver - 404 not found error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, spring-restcontroller

I wish use `JasperReport` with `Spring MVC`, but I use `InternalResourceViewResolver` as a handling method. And when I call my report method it starts searching `pdfReport.jsp` page and shows me a `404 not found`. But I need open report file, not the `.jsp` page!

**My Controller method :**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/report/{id}")
public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    LOG.debug("--------------generate PDF report----------");

    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    java.util.List<Node> nodeList = nodeService.list();
    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(nodeList);
    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);

    // pdfReport bean has ben declared in the spring configuration
    return new ModelAndView("pdfReport", parameterMap);
}
```

**My spring xml file configuration:**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.datum.fnd">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Report pages beans  -->     
<bean id="pdfReport"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="classpath:reportTest.jrxml"
      p:reportDataKey="datasource" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the some changes :

1)Add follwing code to your spring xml configuration file :

```
<!--  Jasper report  -->
<import resource="jasper-views.xml"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring/jasper-views.xml"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

2)Create new jasper-views.xml file , copy and paste follwing codes to it:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<!--here all the url value should contains the valid path for the jrxml file-->

<bean id="pdfReport"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="classpath:reportTest.jrxml"
      p:reportDataKey="datasource" />
</beans>
```